# Jetty: Way to get request and response byte size current request processing?

Tags: java, servlets, jetty

In a Servlet context using Jetty, I would like to know the number of bytes a request was, and the number of bytes the response was (not only the content) - this so that I can log and do stats on this in a Filter upon exiting out.

So far, I've found this:

For response content, I've found that the `HttpServletResponse` object is a `HttpOutput`, on which there is a `getWritten()` returning the number of bytes written - and also, there is a `getHttpChannel()` returning a `HttpChannel`, which again has `getBytesWritten()`. However, both of these only return the size of the *content*, evidently not including headers - easily seen by a `302` redirect having size 0.

I have also found that from `HttpChannel`, you can invoke `getHttpTransport()`, which is a `HttpConnection`. This has nice "bytesIn" and "bytesOut" LongAdders, which evidently do include all bytes - *however*, this is for the *Connection*, and thus with keep-alive, this includes the bytes for *all* request/responses that this Connection has performed, thus increasing for each request/response cycle that Connection is a part of. (Also, on `HttpChannel`, there is a `getRequests()`, which returns the number of requests served with this instance, some kind of average could seemingly be obtained).

Thus: Is there a way to get the total request and response byte sizes for the current request? Bonus for size of *content* of request too. (I realize that there are two "sizes" to take into account: The one over the wire, which can be compressed, and the actual uncompressed size).